# %Like% Query in spring JpaRepositoryn

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to write a like query in JpaRepository but it is not returning anything.

Here is my code :

```
@Query(value = "select * from DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG C JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_PERS B ON 

    B.NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG_ID=C.NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG_ID JOIN GRR_PARTY GRR ON GRR.PERS_ID =B.PERS_ID JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG D ON C.NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG_ID=D.NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG_ID JOIN DC_SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG E ON E.SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG_ID= C.SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG_ID JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED F ON F.NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED_ID=C.NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED_ID JOIN DC_ORG G ON C.ORG_ID=G.ORG_ID WHERE C.ORG_ID=:orgId AND GRR.PERS_ID=:persId  AND C.ACT_IND=1 AND STRT_DT LIKE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:%strtDt%,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AND ROWNUM<2",nativeQuery = true)

    List<Notlist> ifNotificationExist(@Param("orgId") Long orgId, @Param("persId") Long persId,@Param("strtDt") LocalDate strtDt);
```

Comment: You're supposed to use `%` at the beginning and/or end of the value, not in the parameters of a function

Comment: @NickAth Thanks for the response I already tried no luck

Comment: @NickAth Now I'm getting this error "ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments"

Comment: As @ayrton very rightly mentions, you are not placing the '%' at the correct place. Try instead of TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:%strtDt%,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') to add this LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT (TO_DATE(:strtDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'%') ) 

The concat function accepts two parameters

Comment: Your query is very strange. You should ask a question about what it is you want to query which I imagine can be done much more easily and robustly using standard Oracle date functions rather than hacking about with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```sql
 /* as before ...*/
to_char(STRT_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') LIKE '%'||to_char(:strtDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'%' 
/*...*/
```

...and I think even:

```sql
to_char(STRT_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_char(:strtDt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

..would be good!

Since:

```sql
... STRT_DT LIKE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:%strtDt%,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') ...
```

is very strange/odd!

Assumptions:

- You are on oracle db.
- `:strDt` is a `java.util.LocalDate` input variable.
- `STRT_DT` is a "date type" (DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP) column.
- You want to filter the query by "date equality"(only the year month day portion) of `:strtDt` param and `STRT_DT` column .

Comment: still it is not returning anything

Comment: ..then good luck! (you have 6  (INNER!) `join`s in that query)

Comment: I'm little bit surprise when I'm executing script without  STRT_DT in where clause  it is executing successfully with other where clause.

Comment: maybe you should specify which `STRT_DT` you mean (alias in your query: `B., C., GRR....`? )

Comment: I specified but no luck

Comment: ..then it can be only in the data: show us a sample column + input